# Extracting the Different Pack Components [R]

Tags: r

I wanted to find the unit of measure in pack.
Here I have a field as below.

```
pack <- c("1X7CL ML", "2X3ML CLose","24X33cl Ltront","24X1LTR CLear", "192X5cl mlow")
```

I need to extract 3 Components here: 
1) Number of eaches in a pack. This is the first number in the pack just before the X
2) Then the volume in each pack. This is the second number in the pack just after the X
3) The third is the UOM that is mentioned just after the volume number [it is important that only the first UOM occurrence is taken into account because there could be other texts after that)

The below are the 3 standard UOM that will only occur but could be in caps or small letter.

```
UOM <- c("CL","ML","LTR")
```

I would like the result to give me 3 vectors:

1) Number in each pack: 1 2 24 24 192
2) Volume in each pack: 7 3 33 1 5
3) UOM in each pack: CL ML CL LTR CL

In case of getting the first result (i.e. Number in each pack) I have the below code which works fine:

```
as.numeric(gsub("(.*?)(X.*)", "\\1", pack))
```

I would appreciate anyone's help to extract the others.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub(".*X(\\d+).*", "\\1", pack))` and `toupper( gsub(".*X\\d+(\\S+).*", "\\1", pack))`

Comment: The second result worked here: thanks!

Comment: In case of the 3rd not every data points worked. the below is some additional pack data that does not word added to the pack list. pack <- c("1X7CL ML", "2X3ML CLose","24X33cl Ltront","24X1LTR CLear", "192X5cl mlow",
          "12X1.14 LTR (LTO)", "12X1.125 LTR (DOK)", "6X1LTR NRF (JRF)", "12X1LTR NRF (LTO)",
          "6X75CL (Jacobs) 2014")

Comment: Could you please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'pack' showed i the OP's example didn't include the decimal points.  If we include as pattern.  We match character (`.*`) until the 'X' followed by one or more digits with decimals (`[0-9.]+`) and zero or more space (`\\s*` - to account for cases where there are spaces), capture the non-white space characters as a group (`(\\S+)`) and in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*X[0-9.]+\\s*(\\S+).*", "\\1", pack)
#[1] "CL"  "ML"  "cl"  "LTR" "cl"  "LTR" "LTR" "LTR" "LTR" "CL"
```

and for the second question. we capture the numbers (not sure if the decimals needs to be captured)

```
as.numeric(sub(".*X(\\d+).*", "\\1", pack))
# [1]  7  3 33  1  5  1  1  1  1 75
```

If we also need the decimals

```
as.numeric(sub(".*X(\\d+[.]*\\d*).*", "\\1", pack))
#[1]  7.000  3.000 33.000  1.000  5.000  1.140  1.125  1.000  1.000 75.000
```

Note that a `vector` or column of data.frame can have a single `class`.  By using `as.numeric`, all the elements are converted to `numeric` class.

#### data

```
pack <- c("1X7CL ML", "2X3ML CLose","24X33cl Ltront","24X1LTR CLear", 
 "192X5cl mlow", "12X1.14 LTR (LTO)", "12X1.125 LTR (DOK)",
  "6X1LTR NRF (JRF)", "12X1LTR NRF (LTO)", "6X75CL (Jacobs) 2014")
```

Comment: The volume field is used for future conversion purposes to a standard unit of measure. If we leave out the decimals these measure could go wrong. It would be great if there is a way to get the decimal data too.

Comment: @Ashwin Did you meant `as.numeric(sub(".*X(\\d+[.]*\\d*).*", "\\1", pack))`